# javascript redirect only pc users not mobile

Tags: javascript, redirect, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am trying to redirect pc users who are using adblock to a certain page.but i dont want to redirect mobile users.

here is my code

```
<script src="/assets/js/ads.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
//the bait for adblock

<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById('ElvJCLbfcHDP')){
  alert('Blocking Ads: No');
} else {
  alert('Blocking Ads: Yes');
}
```

as you can see this only shows if the ads are blocked or not.but what I want to do is check if users are coming from mobile or PC then redirect only PC adblock users to a certain page and let mobile users use site as it is.

i found this

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

but as u can see it only detects if users is from mobile and then run the code.i want it to check if user is from PC and then run the redirect

Answer (score 1):

Use [`!` logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) to alter the statement

```
if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // Desktop / pc
}
```

Comment: let me give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to redirect based on a test for a device.. You'll spend every moment of your time updating the list and wondering why some devices that are on your list are getting through. `navigator.userAgent` is notoriously unreliable.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)**:

> **Deprecated** This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible;
>   see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your
>   decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.
>
> The NavigatorID.userAgent read-only property returns the user agent
>   string for the current browser.
>
> The specification asks browsers to provide as little information via
>   this field as possible. Never assume that the value of this property
>   will stay the same in future versions of the same browser. **Try not
>   to use it at all**, or only for current and past versions of a
>   browser. New browsers may start using the same UA, or part of it, as
>   an older browser: you really have no guarantee that the browser agent
>   is indeed the one advertised by this property.
>
> **Also keep in mind that users of a browser can change the value of this field if they want (UA spoofing).**

Typically, a desktop can be rooted out simply by the width of the window (as measured in CSS pixels, not hardware pixels).

```
if(window.innerWidth > 1280){
   location.href = "desktop path";
} else {
   location.href = "mobile path";
}
```

Comment: looks more reliable.but if i want to get value first and then redirect users based on the value  from (document.getElementById('ElvJCLbfcHDP')). if its blocking then ony it should redirect.
sorry this is my first time with javascript and did a lot of google.but kind of need to fix it asap

Comment: @NawafGantare See my updated answer. It has never been reliable.

Comment: i dont mind all those spoofing and thing.since its just a adblocker script i am just trying to finish it asap.here is what i am trying to do
[http://pastebin.com/raw/BTkPJ4vj](http://pastebin.com/raw/BTkPJ4vj)
i want to check if the element is present.IF yes then do nothing and if it is not present and the screen size is more than 1280 then redirect users to that page.this way only pc users will get redirected and not mobile users even if they are blocking ads.can u please help me fix the code